# Proving that $\sin{2y}(\tan{x}+\tan{y}) = 1$ implies $y=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{x}{2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I show manipulate the first equation to get the second (when $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0\leq y\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$)?
$$\sin{2y}(\tan{x}+\tan{y}) = 1$$
$$y=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{x}{2}$$
The equations are equal, by the way (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xwr9c33o3a).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\tan x &= \frac 1{\sin 2y}-\tan y
\\&=\frac1{2\sin y \cos y}-\frac {2\sin^2 y}{2 \sin y\cos y}
\\&=\frac{\cos 2y}{\sin 2y}
\\&=\frac1{\tan 2y}
\\&=\tan \left(\frac \pi2-2y\right)
\end{align}$$

Since $\tan$ is bijective on your interval, we have $x=\dfrac \pi2-2y$.

That is, $y= \dfrac \pi4-\dfrac x2$.

Comment: Oh !! I didn;t really get that He wanted to reach the equation starting from the first :( My bad ! I misunderstood the question